# Bundle install wants to install different gem version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, gemfile, gemfile.lock

I am trying to run a `bundle install` in my Ruby project.  But it tries to install rake -v 11.1.2 which requires Ruby 1.9.3. (I am using 1.8.7-p374 - please don't kill me!)

None of my Gemfiles have this version specified and I already have rake version 10.1.1 installed.  I want to know which other gem needs this particular version.

Here is my `gem dependency -R` output => http://pastebin.com/BqTnPYvf

Can anyone please guide me through this?

Comment: Yes, this seems odd, almost like a bug in bundler. Would you mind pasting the entire Gemfile? It might be reproducible.

Comment: Here is the Gemfile - http://pastebin.com/ERVYipNJ

Comment: Also let me point out that I have other Ruby versions like `ree-1.8.7-2012.02`, `ruby-1.8.7-head` and `ruby-2.0.0-p647`. Can those be interfering?